# Extjs 3.4 not fully working in GateIn 3.6 - Closure compiler compression issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-closure-compiler, gatein

I am using ext-js version 3.4 with GateIn 3.6 (jboss as 7). On GateIn some ext components are not working fine (especially tree) when GateIn as in production mode. I think this issue is due to javascript compression mechanism. I got the same issue in GateIn 3.2  then after i find that in GateIn 3.6 they changed the java compression machanism (in this GateIn they are using [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)) but still have the same issue.
Here follows my problem with example

I created two examples which contains same code of tree loading
[Example 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t49voqlrz82bcoe/ext-original.zip) :- Here the ext js related files are not compressed
[Example 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bodejbvi4047ql/ext-compressed.zip) :- Here the ext js files are compressed using [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)
(You can run the above two example by deploying it into a server like wamp, xamp, jboss... etc)

On Example 1 it is possible to expand the tree. But on the second case ([Example 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bodejbvi4047ql/ext-compressed.zip)) the tree expanded only first level. Is there is any idea to resolve this issue.

I cant directly specify the ext js libraries without compression in production mode. Because in GateIn java scripts are specified inside in gatein-resources.xml file. In production mode i think by default GateIn compresses the files in gatein-resources.xml using closure compiler.

Comment: Where do you use ext-js ? In a portlet ?

Comment: Yes in portlet.In my portlets some components are created using ext-js. I need ext-js libraries in all portlets in my application so i put extjs libraries in gatein-resources.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If non compressing your ext-js scripts is an option for you, you can either :
- add your scripts with the doHeaders method instead of using gatein-resources.xml : [Remove duplicate header entries from doHeaders()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796203/remove-duplicate-header-entries-from-doheaders)
- keep on using the gatein-resources.xml to import your javascripts, and make an exception for the compression by adding a route in the gatein/conf/controller.xml (a route which does not get the compress param) :

```
<route path="/scripts/{gtn:version}/{gtn:scope}/">
  <route-param qname="gtn:handler">
    <value>script</value>
  </route-param>
  <path-param qname="gtn:version" encoding="preserve-path">
    <pattern>[^/]*</pattern>
  </path-param>
  <route path="/{gtn:resource}{gtn:lang}-min.js">
    <path-param qname="gtn:resource">
      <pattern>(ext-core-debug)</pattern>
    </path-param>
    <path-param qname="gtn:lang" capture-group="true">
      <pattern>-([A-Za-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?)|</pattern>
    </path-param>
  </route>
</route>

<route path="/scripts/{gtn:version}/{gtn:scope}/">
  <route-param qname="gtn:handler">
    <value>script</value>
  </route-param>
  <path-param qname="gtn:version" encoding="preserve-path">
    <pattern>[^/]*</pattern>
  </path-param>
  <route path="/{gtn:resource}{gtn:lang}{gtn:compress}.js">
    <path-param qname="gtn:resource">
      <pattern>.+?</pattern>
    </path-param>
    <path-param qname="gtn:lang" capture-group="true">
      <pattern>-([A-Za-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?)|</pattern>
    </path-param>
    <path-param qname="gtn:compress" capture-group="true">
      <pattern>-(min)|</pattern>
    </path-param>
  </route>
</route>
```

Adapt the pattern of the gtn:resource param to match your needs.
With one of these solutions, all the scripts will be minified except the ones you define in your pattern.